# unable to render static files in Django 2.2

Tags: django, django-2.2

I just started working on a project where the previous developer was using django 2.2

Ideally, leaving the complexity aside, one would need to define `STATIC_URL='/static/'` in settings.py file and use `{% load 'static' %}` in base html file while appending required details in urls.py file.

However, in the current project, all of the static content (css, js) is stored in single media folder.

and in settings.py file, i have

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/usr/local/my34project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

also in base html file, they have

```
<link href="/media/css/backoffice/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

instead of

```
<link href="{% static 'css/backoffice/fonts.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

How is it, that the previous person's project was working without static being loaded or used in the url link ?

Comment: If you set `DEBUG = False`, the static files will no longer be served. Note that if you use `{% extend ... %}` and the parent template has a `{% load static %}`, you do not need to load it a second time.

Comment: Does the urls.py file have a `static()` entry? That's probably how files in `/media/` get served when DEBUG = True. But it's pretty bad practice indeed. Your `STATIC_ROOT` setting is really wrong. First it's not required in development mode, but more important, it should not point to an existing directory of a package! It's where Django **copies** all static files when running `collectstatic` so it should be a special directory for that purpose.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : other html templates are using `extends` but the parent template, which is the base.html file in my case, does not have `{% load static %}`. There are css and js files listed in both base.html and other html files that extend base, all of them have hardcoded urls for css and js files and they all seem to working without any error.

Comment: @dirkgroten , projects level urls.py has `from django.conf.urls.static import static
` imported but it is not being referenced or used along with urlspatterns. also no mention of static in app level urls.py file

Comment: you're sure there isn't something like `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`?

Comment: no `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` or `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` in project's urls.py or app's urls.py